# Expanding Rows in NSTableView

Tags: swift, macos, appkit

Is it possible to collapse/expand rows in an `NSTableView` in the same way as an `NSOutlineView`?

I would like to mimic the behaviour of `NSOutlineView` in `NSTableView`.

Comment: Why can't you just use `NSOutlineView`?

Comment: Certainly a possibility - I was wondering if there was a way to avoid refactoring numerous files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide rows with `NSTableView.hideRows(at indexes: IndexSet, withAnimation: NSTableView.AnimationOptions = [])`.

You can show rows with `NSTableView.unhideRows(at indexes: IndexSet, withAnimation rowAnimation: NSTableView.AnimationOptions = [])`.

You can get the indexes of hidden rows with `NSTableView.hiddenRowIndexes`.

Note that hiding and showing rows fire certain `NSTableViewDelegate` methods. See the documentation for details.

Comment: You are my god. The animations `slideUp` and `slideDown` are exactly what I needed.